# Google Analytics - Data Storage

Tags: google-analytics

I am new to Google Analytics and found a very interesting help subject on how IP masking works that details that some IP data is dropped by the collector before it is stored in the google analytics database.

I have a question around how the similar behaviour works for 1. Filters and 2. Exclude URL Query Parameters option within view settings.

Basically for each all data will be sent to Google BUT does the data I have excluded using these methods ever get actually databased? with the data excluded being removed from the view served in the GUI / API **OR** does the data I have excluded get dropped at collection before it is databased. I guess the answer could be different for Filters and Exclude URL Query Parameters.

Many Thanks

Comment: Ultimately this can only be answered by Google (it's technically possible that they store "removed" data somewhere and just don't tell you), but as per documentation and for all practical purposes  Filters and query exclusion are desctructive operations and you cannot access the data thus removed. Plus I'm not convinced that this a good question for stackoverflow.

Comment: Not sure why understanding what is databased by a solution such as GA is not a good question for stackoverflow? something anyone using the solution or as an IT Professional implementing it as part of a solution should really know - I would have thought? How else would you know if non functional requirements around data storage, data privacy etc are met as a solution provider?

Comment: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." That's given as a reason to close a question in the "vote for close" dialog. Plus why would anybody except the vendor himself know the inner workings of a proprietary software ?

Comment: Mmmm I really think it is important to understand, as a solution provider, what happens to data your "software" creates/consumes, how this data is then processed and where it is then stored. This is the case if you are are writing the whole solution yourself or using a third party tool as part of an end to end solution. This is especially true if some or part of the data is sensitive or restricted in some way. Any tips on how to ask Google? If I find out I will let you know - you never know when it might pop up!

Comment: Imagine for a moment that you were involved in implementing very basic page level analytics but for some reason the page URL had Name, Sex and DOB and address info as a query string on the URL. Imagine also that changing the web site is out of scope. Would excluding the query string using GA Settings stop that data from being stored wherever the GA database is in the world ;-)